# How to publish docker image as an artifact in azure devops

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am building a Docker image in my Azure pipeline. Now, I want to push this image to multiple aws accounts(dev, stage, prod) depending on the configuration parameters. The problem is, image is not available in publish artifact. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61192774/accessing-docker-images-in-a-multi-stage-azure-devops) and [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/3447) article during my research. I am confused about the solution regarding saving the docker image so it can be available in publish artifact. I have two specific questions:

1. How will I use the `docker save` command in Azure pipeline task after docker build. The available docker task doesn't have this command.
2. Is there any better way of doing this apart from saving an image.

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: I found this article https://dev.to/n3wt0n/container-image-promotion-across-environments-build-artifact-5887 and my issue got resolved.

Comment: Hi @RamanBalyan, Thanks for the sharing, do you mind converting the comment into answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of reserach I found this article which resolved my issue https://dev.to/n3wt0n/container-image-promotion-across-environments-build-artifact-5887

Note: We can manually add commands which are not present in the Docker task snippet available in Azure DevOps. This is also mentioned in the article and steps to do this.

Answer (score 14):

Nowadays the preferred way of writing pipelines is with yaml.

Please see my code on how to do it in a multistage pipeline with Artifactory docker registry.

If we are in master the the MY_ADDITIONAL_TAG will be also pushed.

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build DevOps base image
  jobs:
  - job: Build_and_Push
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: ''
        repository: 'MY_REPO/IMAGE'
        command: 'build'
        Dockerfile: 'PATH_TO_MY_DOCKERFILE'
        tags: $(tag)
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Save Docker Image
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          docker save MY_DOCKER_REPO_IMAGE_NAME:$(tag) -o $(Pipeline.Workspace)/MY_IMAGE_FILE.tar
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/MY_IMAGE_FILE.tar'
        artifact: 'MY_ARTIFACT'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
- stage: Push
  displayName: Push DevOps base image
  jobs:
  - job: Push
    steps:
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        artifactName: 'MY_ARTIFACT'
        targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Load Docker Image
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |      
          docker load --input $(Pipeline.Workspace)/MY_IMAGE_FILE.tar
          docker tag MY_DOCKER_REPO_IMAGE_NAME:$(tag) MY_DOCKER_REPO_IMAGE_NAME:MY_ADDITIONAL_TAG
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: push development tags
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'MY_DOCKER_REGISTRY'
        repository: 'MY_REPO/IMAGE'
        command: 'push'
        tags: | 
          $(tag)
    - task: Docker@2
      condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
      displayName: push 0-devops tag
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'MY_ARTIFACT'
        repository: 'MY_REPO/IMAGE'
        command: 'push'
        tags: | 
          MY_ADDITIONAL_TAG
```

Answer (score 4):

> How will I use the `docker save` command in Azure pipeline task after docker build. The available docker task doesn't have this command.

This related to the task version.

Steps: Add task docker->switch the task version to **0**->select the option `Run a Docker command`, then we could run the `docker save` command, check the pic below.

[image]

> Is there any better way of doing this apart from saving an image.

We recommend that you use this to upload the docker image as an artifact.